# Where to define common functions in Ocaml?

Tags: function, module, ocaml

I have some very basic and simple functions shared by several `.ml` files: for instance, warn, error... I would like to know, instead of repeating their definition in each `.ml` file, how to define them in a common place, and just call them when necessary? Is it necessarily a module?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every file in OCaml defines a module. For instance, you could place your common definitions in:

```
(* common.ml *)
let error msg = ...
let warn  msg = ...
```

And then use it from other files as such:

```
... Common.error "Naughty event!" ...
```

Or as such:

```
open Common

... error "Naughty event!" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Another question is if this `.ml` file needs to be compiled to be opened/used in other files, which types of file are actually required: `.ml, .mli, .cmi, .cmx, .o`?

Comment: You need `.cmi` and either `.cmx` or `.cmo` depending on whether you're using `ocamlopt` or `ocamlc` (respectively).